# Ionic android application - JWplayer not working in specific devices

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jwplayer

My Ionic android application stream videos from Wowza server with advertisement.Its working perfectly fine when testing in browser using

> ionic serve

also working fine after building apk file and installed in mobile devices.

The problem occurs in some specific devices like samsung galaxy s6 and Note4.

JWplayer play button is not working on these devices.

But video thumbnails are showing correctly on these devices,but only problem is with play button.

```
$scope.paramData=$stateParams;
jwplayer('playerMDnYyJnMcAHv').setup({
  flashplayer:"js/jwplayer.flash.swf",
  file:  $stateParams.playlistUrl,
  image: $stateParams.poster,
  width: '100%',
  aspectratio: '16:9',
  androidhls: 'true',
  stretching: "exactfit",
  skin: "bekle",
  advertising: {
         client: 'vast',
         tag   : $stateParams.vast,
          },
           cast:{
              appid:"724D0CE5565",
              } 
         });
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue .?

Comment: sorry Ethan. i am developing a mobile android application.There is no link i can provide for you.

Comment: We do have an official SDK for Android that you can use - http://www.jwplayer.com/products/mobile-sdk/

Comment: we already having jwplayer enterprise key.need to pay  for sdk also ? our application plays vast ads,so i hope sdk enterprise edition should be used ?

Comment: Please email support <at> jwplayer <dot> com directly about this, then.

Answer (score 2):

JWplayer is having issues with webview of s6 and Note4. So instead of trying other things, install [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) plugin to your project, then build .apk file. Behaviour of JWplayer will become stable on all devices. Command to install `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` or if you are running older version of cordova then `ionic plugin add https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have tried your command but getting following error  

 "   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" via plugin registry
Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
    at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:304:14)
    at Request._callback"

Comment: @yadhukrishnan may be you are using older version of cordova, i have updated my answer. try second command.

Comment: already added crosswalk plugin but still problem remains same.i figuredout same issue in samsung galaxy s4.do anyone think its common issue for samsung devices ? or may be jwplayer version ? curently i am using version 6.

Comment: We have never really tested the player inside of a webview or using phonegap/cordova.